# Minimizar todas las ventanas abiertas e ir al escritorio con un .bat

Tags: batch

Quiero minimizar todas las ventanas abiertas para ir al escritorio. Mi idea es crear un .bat para hacerlo y después poner un acceso directo en la barra de tareas a este .bat
Gracias[image: En la imagen se ven 7 ventanas]

Comment: Mira si esto te sirve: https://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-minimize-all-windows/1017

Comment: Es importante mostrar algo de investigación al realizar la pregunta, mostrar interés por resolverla. Sería bueno que lo intentaras los problemas que no con las dudas que surjan puedes hacer las preguntas específicas. Querer hacer algo (en su mayoría tareas o trabajos personales) y pedirle a otro que lo haga por ti bien podría ser una trabajo remunerado, la filosofía de este foro (creo) es un apoyo mutuo entre programadores, no es realizar tareas ni trabajos voluntarios. Recuerda, personas están dándote su tiempo libre para ayudarte a resolver tus dudas, al menos muestra un interés en intentarl

Comment: Será conveniente programar algo en lugar de escribir un script de consola. https://stackoverflow.com/a/838931/13419694

Answer (score 0):

la verdad lo intente pero con un archivo .bat no me funciono, pero con python si funciona. El algoritmo es

```
import pyautogui as key

key.hotkey('win','d')
```

debes instalar Python en cualquier version desde la 3.8.0
luego instalas la librería pyautogui --> pip install PyAutoGUI
y creas un archivo python en el ide de tu preferencia, ahí escribes las 2 líneas de arriba y listo lo guardas

-seguido de ello buscas el archivo en la ubicación que lo hayas guardado y cambias la terminación .py por .exe y esto lo anclas a la barra de tareas

-ahora nuevamente cambia el nombre del archivo por la terminacion .pyw (esto para que se ejecute en segundo plano)

-en el archivo anclado da click derecho, ahí debe salir el archivo nuevamente, sobre ese archivo das click derecho nuevamente y escoges la opción propiedades

-en la ventada que se abre, en la opción destino cambia la terminación .exe por .pyw y listo

ahora cuando presiones ese archivo se minimizaran todas las ventanas que tengas abiertas y de igual manera si no todas están minimizadas las mostrara nuevamente

espero te funcione saludos.

Comment: Buenos días:
 Agradezco la respuesta pero de momento no tengo intención de trabajar con Python. Llevo muchos días buscando algo tan simple como gestionar ventanas desde cmd: concluyo que no existen tales comandos.     
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

la única solución que se me ocurre es haciendo uso de un Acceso directo propio de Windows que se encuentra en **C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Shows Desktop.lnk** y poniéndolo en la barra de tareas.

O bien, si quieres hacer el script en .batch:

```
@ECHO OFF

START %APPDATA%\Microsoft\"Internet Explorer"\"Quick Launch"\"Shows Desktop.lnk"
```

Comment: Gracias Álex, el script funciona, pero ahora me ha surgido un problema imprevisto: no puedo poner el acceso directo en la barra de tareas. He escrito el script que me has mandado, lo he copiado en C:, he creado un acceso directo en el escritorio, he cambiado el icono y lo arrastro a la barra de tareas pero no se queda.

Comment: Con que no te se queda en la barra de tareas te refieres a que desde un principio no te deja anclarlo, o que lo anclas y al reiniciar el equipo se quita?

Comment: No me deja anclarlo.  Lo arrastro y sale el icono de "prohibido aparcar" ¿Quizás por ser una bat?. 
Saludos

Comment: Con los bats nunca tuve ese problema al anclarlos a la barra de tareas. Encontré que puede ser por algún problema de alguna actualización, aquí pone una solución para ese problema [https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/windows-10-no-puedo-anclar-programasiconosaccesos/bbb2e134-0e59-47a5-bafc-635b980b2a3e](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/windows-10-no-puedo-anclar-programasiconosaccesos/bbb2e134-0e59-47a5-bafc-635b980b2a3e)